# symfony2 form bindRequest returns 500 error

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-2.2

so i have a form type "PictureType":

```
<?php

namespace AB\MyBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;

class PictureType extends AbstractType
{
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder ->add('picture','file');
    }

public function getName()
{
    return 'ab_mybundle_picturetype';
}

        public function useDefaultOptions(array $options)
{
    return array(
        'data_class' => 'AB\MyBundle\Form\Model\Picture'
    );
}
}
```

entity  Picture:

```
<?php

namespace AB\MyBundle\Form\Model;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

class Picture 
{

/**
 * @Assert\Image(maxSize="800000")
 */

public $picture;

}
```

the controller:

```
use AB\MyBundle\Form\Type\PictureType;
use AB\MyBundle\Form\Model\Picture;
 ...
 ...

$form = $this->createForm(new PictureType, new Picture); 
    if( $this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST' )
    {
    echo "1"; // 1 is printed
        $form->bindRequest($this->get('request')); // this line gives the error

        echo "2"; // 2 is not printed
        if( $form->isValid() )
        {

         }
    }

    return $this->render("ABMyBundle:Default:pic.html.twig",array(
            'form' => $form->createview()

    ));
```

when i submit the form it gives me an 500 error

```
"The controller must return a response (null given). Did you forget to add a return statement somewhere in your controller?"
```

can someone help me :(  ?

Answer (score 2):

```
$form = $this->createForm(new PictureType, new Picture); 
if( $this->get('request')->getMethod() == 'POST' )
{
    echo "1";
    $form->bind($request);         
    if( $form->isValid() )
    {
       echo "2"; 
    }
}
```

Refer the link:
http://symfony.com/blog/form-goodness-in-symfony-2-1
https://github.com/symfony/symfony/pull/4811

Answer (score 1):

Don't use echo, controller must return a response:

```
    $form->bindRequest($this->get('request')); // this line gives the error

    if( $form->isValid() )
    {
         return new Response('Hello world!');
    }
```